# Should we "enable a banner to warn about [our] policy on AI-generated content"?

Tags: discussion, status-review

A post on main meta is stating ["Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/310650), so given that it seems to be general consensus on SFF that we should [not allow AI content](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13817/57310), should we request to enable this feature?

[image]

I understand the ultimate decision will probably have to be initiated by our "diamond moderators", but I feel it worthy for the community to discuss the issue or for the moderators to let us know what they might be planning already.

Comment: Chances are those same users won't even read, let alone notice, the banner, but I'm all in favour, in the off chance that it can help.

Comment: @Clockwork - Even if it only dissuades a few, that's still worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for creating this post. Ping a mod in a week or two, when this has had enough time that the consensus is unarguably clear, and we'll slap a [meta-tag:status-review] tag on it to get this implemented.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I see the status-review tag has been added. Does this mean it is in the hands of CMs to implement?

Comment: @Skooba Yes, should be.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes, absolutely we should ask for this to be implemented with immediate effect.**

There was an overwhelming consensus in favour of banning AI-generated content (26:1) with no dissenting posts in favour. The vast majority of ChatGPT and Bard copied answers we've seen on this site are of a very low quality, typically filled with 'hallucinations' and generally misleading content, always without sourcing.

**In short, having a big banner saying "Don't do that" would be a useful addition.**

Comment: Possibly referencing that the AI can be a starting point for making an answer, but is not an answer itself, the same way that Wikipedia used to be referenced.